# How to use a transcript with wrong course names in my application

Tags: application, administration, transcript-of-records, france

The transcript for my last year of master's contains severe errors in course names. I will need it fixed if I want to apply to PhD programs, otherwise my chances would diminish.

- The master program's director confirmed the error and gave me the correct course names.
- The dean of computer science agreed that it's an error and asked the registrar to issue a fixed version.
- The **registrar refused to fix it**, because it's been "administratively validated". The dean apparently can't order them to change their minds.

As a result, the dean of CS **wants me to send them a fixed version** so they can validate it and add the department's official stamp.

I would like to know how to go about writing this, so that the departments I will apply to don't think I'm sending them a fake. The dean will retire soon, so they won't be in their position if a school wants to contact them to confirm that the fixed transcript is valid.

I don't have the model the registrar uses for the transcripts. I could re-write a different document in Microsoft Word, or scan the existing one and digitally alter it. Both will probably look dodgy to someone who can see the other years' transcripts.

There is no web service for other schools to verify the transcripts. I'm the only student asking for this, as far as I'm aware.

What is the best way to write this document and attach it to my applications to avoid suspicions and delays?

Comment: This is odd. What country is this in and where do you hope to apply?

Comment: It's France. I haven't decided where to apply yet, but probably in several EU countries, and maybe the US too.

Comment: And yes, I'm aware that this is an odd situation. The registrar at my school is often unhelpful and this master has had huge administrative issues for several years. I think the dean and program director know this and are trying to help, but they can't do much more than this.

Comment: Can you give an example of an incorrectly translated course name, along with the "fixed" ones? Is it bad enough to actually confuse anyone?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Several courses that are central to my degree go from "exactly the field I'm applying in" to "a completely unrelated area of computer science". It's bad enough to confuse someone.

Comment: Is the error in the English translations of the course names?

Comment: @orna Can you give actual examples?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni No, it's just a totally different name. As I understood, the profs re-used a "slot" used by an older course, but somehow didn't manage to change their name, so a machine learning course becomes a virtual reality one (but has nothing to do with VR and everything to do with ML), etc.

Comment: Oh wow. What a disaster. I'd be deeply embarrassed as the dean.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni This was two years ago. The current year's transcript still has the same error. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to avoid any suggestion of impropriety. Find a way to send them a packet of documentation including the official transcript and the communication stream with the various administrators.

But don't try to pass off an unofficial document as an official one. They might be confused a bit but these sorts of things can happen.

You may want the administrators (director and dean) to provide you an electronic version of a signed document. Something like a pdf that you can pass on. Make sure that it includes contact information such as email addresses so that anyone can confirm what is going on.

This is a bit harder with online submissions, I know, so you may need to find a way to supplement that.

---

Separately, if your university has a student ombuds or similar (quasi-legal process) you might want to file a complaint against the registrar for improper behavior: putting their own procedures in place to the detriment of students. Or simple incompetence.